# How to correctly set virtual hosts on Ningx?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, cherrypy, uwsgi

Trying to setup Nginx handling 2 domains I stucked with some problems. While my setup with two domains works correctly with static html handling, tried to push forward and start two python apps behind Nginx. I tried with some differents wsgi containers, and different micro frameworks, but the problem is that Nginx can't handle virtual hosts, rather it serves only one app at both domain adresses.

Here is Nginx conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 8;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    server {
      listen 80;
      server_name www.domainA.com;
      root /var/www/domainA.com;

      location / {
         proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
         proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header    X-Originating-IP    $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header    HTTP_REMOTE_ADDR    $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header    REMOTE_ADDR         $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header    CLIENT_IP           $remote_addr;
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.2:7000;
      }
    }
    server {
      listen 80;
      server_name www.domainB.com;
      root /var/www/domainB.com;

      location / {
... ... blah blah...same story...except this proxy pass.....
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
      }
    }
}
```

Any help ?

**EDIT:**

Just tried to add empty server block as 1st block and it return 404.

Comment: may be you have to use different listen port for www.domainB.com

Comment: Are you sure you restarted nginx after config change? Are you visiting `www.domainB.com`, not just `domainB.com`?

Comment: Can you show us your relevant python code?

Answer (score 0):

Are these outward facing websites?

If you put the full ip in your listen clause you should start working correctly.

```
listen 512.548.595.485:80;
```

Right now you have the server ip for both sites which is causing a conflict.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the senario where virtual hosts share an ip and port, nginx selects the right virtual host by comparing the Host header sent by the client to each servers' server_name entry. If you have `curl` use the following to see exactly what you're sending for the Host header:

```
curl -s --trace-ascii - http://www.domainA.com | grep 'Host:'
```

To make your server_name more flexible use the .example.com notation. This is shorthand for  example.com and *.example.com. Or just add as many server_name entries as you need.

Next confirm your apps are listening on the right ips and ports. Shell into your server and try:

```
curl -I 'http://127.0.0.1:5000'
curl -I 'http://127.0.0.2:7000'
```

Comment: It returns the same - 0029: Host: www.domainA.com or 0029: Host: www.domainB.com.....

Comment: @Alex I've added another test. It shouldn't matter, but you might try changing 127.0.0.2 to 127.0.0.1, since you're already listening on different ports.

Comment: I tried this before with no success, that's why I end on 0.2:..Please, see edit in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I ended with such problem. In testing conditions I didn't add all flavours which would make Nginx satisfied. Then I found [THIS LINK](http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/web-server) :

*If the “Host” header field does not match a server name, NGINX will route the request to the default server for this port. The default server is the first one listed in the nginx.conf file. This will be overridden if the default_server parameter is set in the listen directive within a server context. An example is given below.*

Nginx docs and tutorials are dispersed on few web locations so finding few doesn't mean that you got all answers you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is your solution. Create a BASH file whose name should be virtualhost.sh. Copy and paste the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

domain=$1
root="/data/$domain"
block="/etc/nginx/sites-available/$domain"

# Create the Document Root directory
mkdir -p $root

# Assign ownership to your regular user account
chown -R $USER:$USER $root

# Create the Nginx server block file:
tee $block > /dev/null <<EOF 
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /data/$domain;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name $domain www.$domain;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml)$ {
        access_log        off;
        log_not_found     off;
        expires           30d;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

}

EOF

# Link to make it available
ln -s $block /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

# Test configuration and reload if successful
nginx -t && service nginx reload
```

You need call this BASH file:

```
virtualhost.sh www.yourdomain.com
```